# Cycle through unusual JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to cycle through the items I'm getting from a server, with PHP.

The server (not mine) returns data in this format, how can I cycle through each item?

Thank you so much!

```
{"status":"ok","data":[{"id":1,"userid":"9","foto_arriba":"foto1.jpg","foto_abajo":"foto1.jpg","texto_apoyo":"","habitatid":"4","lugarid":"20"},{"id":2,"userid":"9","foto_arriba":"foto2.jpg","foto_abajo":"foto2.jpg","texto_apoyo":"","habitatid":"4","lugarid":"20"}]}
```

Comment: use something like [this](https://3v4l.org/Zu06c)

Comment: Thank you @berend! But cannot mark your answer as correct since its a comment :(

Comment: That's ok, glad I could help. The question is marked as a duplicate, do have a look at the link, it might give you some more pointers.